# Specialization of function template without changing its prototype

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose `A` is some class and I have the following function template with a nontype argument:

```cpp
template <typename T, int v> void func(const T& x);
```

Now I wish to have different implementations for different types `T` e.g. I want to have a general version of `func` for general types (*general* means types that do not have a special version of `func` designed for it) and a special version of `func` for class `A` which is different from the general version. Also, the users of this design call `func` in the following way:

```cpp
func<int,9>(11);
func<A,1>(a); //a is an object of class A
```

My question is, given that function templates are not allowed to be partially specialized and overloading `func` would not allow users to call it in the way of `func<A,1>`, how am I able to correctly implement `func`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just let the type system do the work for you:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

// Default implementation
template <typename T, int v> void func(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << x + v << "\n";
}

// Specialized for A
template <typename T, int v> void func(const A& x) //<-- matches A for argument T
{
    std::cout << "Groovy " << v << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    func<int, 9>(11);
    func<double, 3>(0.14159);
    func<const char*, 3>("uh oh!");
    func<A, 1>(A());
}
```

Output:

```
20
3.14159
oh!
Groovy 1
```

Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sYqEWqrzj)

Comment: It is not a specialization, but an overload. Notice also that `func<int, 42>(A())` will also use that overload.

Answer (score 4):

You can use C++20 *concepts* to do this:

```
#include <concepts>

struct A {};

template <typename T, int v> 
void func(const T& x) {
  // general version
}

template <std::same_as<A> T, int v>
void func(const T& x) {
   // special version
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/nqsfxWbEf)

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, you can use `std::enable_if` to do what you want as [follows](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k1Py5LrsbLoazrDI):

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
};

template <typename T, int v> void func(const T&) //primary template
{
    std::cout<<"primary template"<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, A>::value, int>::type v>
void func(const A&)
{
    std::cout<<"choosen for A"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<v<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{   
    A a;
    func<int, 9>(11);
    func<A, 9>(a);
    
}
```

Thanks to @**Jarod42** for correcting me.(see the comments below and edit history of this post)

Comment: Note that your version also allows you to do weird things like `func<void, 9, int*>(a);` which will also print "choosen for A".

Comment: @NathanPierson Yeah i mentioned it at the end of my answer now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: First, you forget `_t` (or `typename std::enable_if<cond_v<T>>::type`) to `enable_if` to allow to trigger the SFINAE.

Comment: Second, correct `enable_if` usage (which avoid hijacking, and allow extra overload) is `std::enable_if_t<cond_v<T>, int> = 0` (instead of `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond_v<T>>`).

Comment: @Jarod42 In your second point, i couldn't get it to work. Can you give me a working link to see how this(your 2nd correction) example would look.   And as for your 1st point, i missed to write `_t`. I will correct(add) it .Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LsrteuBKckJcDMft) for second point. `template <typename T,int v, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, A>::value, int>::type = 0>
void func(const A&)`

Comment: @Jarod42 In your given demo, there is no use of `_t` or `::type`. Did you also make a mistake/typo or is it intentional? Also, in the same demo there is no use of `..., int>=0` which you suggested in your previous comment(2nd correction to my code).

Comment: I fixed Demo link (I used your instead of mine) and provide the change in comment too.

Comment: *"Though paddy's answer is more than sufficient."* paddy's answer has pitfall too: `func<int, 42>(A())` uses second overload. (and use wrong term, as it is not a specialization).

Comment: appleapple uses quote to express it is not the right meaning/word, and comments have been done to highlight it was the wrong term...

Comment: @Jarod42 I just realized that this(demo given by you) will allow `func<A, 9, 9>(a);` to work. So to solve this i have now edited my answer to just use 2 template parameters instead of 3. This means now `func<A, 9, 9>(a);` and `func<void, 9, int*>(a);` both won't work. We should've done this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to handle `A` and doesn't need a customization point,
since C++17, you might use `if conxtexpr`:

```
template <typename T, int v>
void func(const T& x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
        // specific code for A
    } else {
        // generic code: Not a A
    }
}
```

Else, you may delegate implementation to other functors/functions that you can customize:

```
template <typename T, int v>
struct func_impl
{
    void operator()(const T&) const { /* Generic code */ }
};

template <typename T, int v> void func(const T& x)
{
    func_impl<T, v>{}(x);
}

// Customization part
class A;

template <int v>
struct func_impl<A, v>
{
    void operator()(const A&) const { /* Specific code for A */ }
};
```

or

```
// Allow both parameters to be deducible, to ease the possibility to overload
// on any part.
template <typename T, int v>
void func_impl(std::integral_constant<int, v>, const T& x)
{
    // Generic code
}

template <typename T, int v> void func(const T& x)
{
    func_impl(std::integral_constant<int, v>{}, x);
}

// Customization point (with ADL)
class A;

template <int v>
void func_impl(std::integral_constant<int, v>, const A& x)
{
    // Specific code for A.
}
```